# Rails: Where none of the associations have a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have books and tags.

```
def Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

def Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

I want to find all books that do **not** have the tag with the **id 1** associated. (They may have no tags.) I tried this:

```
Book.includes(:tags).where.not(tags: { id: 1 })
```

This query finds all books without tags, books that have other tags and **books that *have* the unwanted tag and at least one other tag** associated to them.

How can I filter all books with the certain tag? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Do you mean, that you need to find books that have at least one tag from array of tags with id 1/2/3? Or do you want to obtain books that have all tags at once 1/2/3? Please describe in more details

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I want to get all books that don't have a certain tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/models/books_tag.rb**

```
class BooksTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

**Solution:**

```
Book.where.not(id:
  BooksTag.where(tag_id: 1).select(:book_id)
)
```

- Similar to Anton's answer, I couldn't think of just a one query solution.
- I added the `books_tag` model above so that we won't need to do a JOIN SQL query.

Comment: `BookTags` :), you can get the Book ids with a pluck: `BooksTag.where.not(tag_id: 1).pluck(:book_id).uniq`

Comment: @Gian using `pluck()` will fetch the values from the DB immediately, and return the values as an `array of values` in ruby. However, using `.select()` above doesn't immediately fetch the values from the DB, and that that `.select()` only just still builds up the "query string". This means only one SQL string gets executed (although that string has a subquery), as opposed to using `pluck` which would need two SQL executions (This is assuming your solution is still missing the last step which is `Book.where(id: thebookidsofyourcode)` because I assume the OP wants to receive `Book` records :)

Comment: Yes I agree, you got my up!

Comment: Haha just my two cents. But yours should work too! \\(^-^)/

Comment: Thank you! This is my final code: ```Book.where.not(id: Book.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: 1}))```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is to go with 2 requests. Firstly you get all book ids that have associated tag, then you select all other books.

```
unwanted_book_ids = Books.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: 1 }).pluck('books.id').uniq
@books = Book.where.not(id: unwanted_book_ids)
```

I am not sure that it's the best solution, but, to be honest, I can't find any trivial one without subqueries/unions/etc

Comment: @Railsana Have this helped you? You've been provided with several answers, that should work in 95% of cases, but there is no feedback from you at all :(

Comment: Thank you! I marked the best answer as solution. It works within one call to the database.

Comment: Yes, Jay-Ar Polidario solution is better. I like it, too. But, just you should know... it doesn't work with a one query. In his comment he mentioned, that it's 2 queries

Comment: I can see the query in the terminal, it's really just one. ;)